# Tracing failed login attempts in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, audit, logins

I have some users who are logging in with a wrong password and their accounts get locked.

Now I need to find the source of the failed login attempt. The machine, username etc.

Is it possible to find this?

I did try

```
select ntimestamp#, userid, userhost, spare1, comment$text from sys.aud$ where returncode=1017 order by 1;
```

and also,

```
select OS_USERNAME,USERNAME,USERHOST,to_char(timestamp,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), returncode
from dba_audit_trail 
where returncode > 0
```

Both the above queries show up results but I'm not sure if the results are the ones which actually gets locked.

Server - RHEL
DB - Oracle 12c

Comment: Perhaps you might get lucky looking in listener.log or enable db audit for access.

Comment: listener would show high volume of hits.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right way.
Column RETURNCODE in DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL or RETURN_CODE in UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL view.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-A9993FAC-12D3-4725-A37D-938CC32D74CC.htm#REFRN23023

> This view is populated only in an Oracle Database where unified
>   auditing is not enabled. When unified auditing is enabled in Oracle
>   Database, the audit records are populated in the new audit trail and
>   can be viewed from UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL.

Oracle documentation is always a very good source of information.